# Lie theory for physicists

Tags: reference-request, self-learning, lie-groups, lie-algebras

As an undergraduate on physics seeking a solid education on mathematics, I have recently stumbled upon some theories that make use of the formalism of Lie groups and Lie algebras.

In light of this, I would like to ask where should I look for references in order to learn more about Lie theory and, of course, about its applications on physics, especially in Quantum Mechanics.

Comment: I'm stuying [this text](http://arxiv.org/pdf/math-ph/0005032v1.pdf) about matrix Lie groups. I think it is quite elementary and you might like it. `:)`

Comment: Also, given that a Lie group is a group with a manifold structure, I guess that Differential Geometry is a must. I'll assume that you're not in a hurry to get far with this, so I would recommend taking a look at it in low dimensions, such as $\Bbb R^3$, for starters. Two books that immediately come to mind are [Oprea's](http://www.amazon.com/Differential-Applications-Classroom-Mathematical-Association/dp/0883857480) Differential Geometry and Its Applications book and [O'Neill](http://www.amazon.com/Elementary-Differential-Geometry-Revised-Edition/dp/0120887355)'s Elementary Differential...

Comment: ...Geometry. He also has two more books, about semi-Riemannian Geometry and Black Holes (might as well learn a bit of GR in the way). I'll keep these suggestions as comments, since I'm no expert in Lie theory, and am in fact looking for references too.

Comment: @IvoTerek I'm actually looking through the published version of the first text you linked.  It doesn't assume any background in differential geometry/topology, but nevertheless covers most of the important bits of Lie algebra.  I have the strong feeling that a physicist looking for some basic familiarity can get by without the tangent space definition of the Lie algebra.

Comment: Yes, I think it is great for getting familiarity. All my differential geometry in mainly low-dimensional, I'm only going to take a topology course now, and I'm managing to understand the text quite a bit, actually. If I can get by with this few "pre-requisites", so can OP.

Comment: I think that Loring Tu's [Introduction to Manifolds](http://im0.p.lodz.pl/~kubarski/AnalizaIV/Wyklady/L-Tu-1441973990.pdf) is pretty elementary too, and might be suited for your needs, check it out. About group theory, so far I haven't seen the need for anything too sophisticated (e.g. Sylow theory, solvable groups, etc). The first chapter of the first text I linked may be enough background for the rest of it.

Comment: Try [this one](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6108/comprehensive-book-on-group-theory-for-physicists/524223#524223) in PSE. The "for physicists" books are solid, only focussed on aspects that matter in physics and avoidant of tangential aspects.

Answer (score 4):

I've been in your same situation, and I think this might be the book you're looking for: *[Physics from Symmetry](http://physicsfromsymmetry.com/)*, by Jakob Schwichtenberg. It explains the fundamental concepts of Lie/representation theory carefully, in a quite intuitive manner, motivated via applications in Physics. There is a chapter dedicated exclusively to Quantum Mechanics, which fundamental principles are derived using mathematical tools alone, but you'll also find discussions of QFT, Electromagnetism and Classical Mechanics.

For a more mathematically rigorous approach, I'd recommend [*Naive Lie Theory*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00DWKP2OY) by John Stillwell, also an excellent read, which successfully conveys complex ideas in a simple fashion. You'll specially enjoyed the historical notes at the end of the book.

Finally, I've read some good reviews of [*Group Theory and Physics*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521558859) by Shlomo Sternberg, which appears to be a main reference work.

Answer (score 2):

Well from a point of view of Lie groups theory to be applied to physics there is an elementary book called "Lie groups, physics and geometry" by Robert Gilmore which deals with matrix groups, Lie algebras, even some operator algebras and a small bits on structure of Lie groups. It also includes the standard applications (quantum mechanics, Maxwell eqn.s,..).

But for the more general study of Lie theory one needs quite a bit of topology,differential geometry and algebra (beyond linear algebra.. its good to know things from say commutative algebra,algebraic groups.., so one can study the representation theory of Lie groups..). In this case i would recommend the book by Chevally "Theory of Lie groups".

Comment: @LuísDallaStella the Chevalley requires general topology and some more advanced algebra quite a bit, but i believe before reading it you should at least know the basic on manifolds and it doesn't require any differential geometry dealing with curvature and related topic..

Answer (score 0):

Ok I would add the best book I have ever seen is **Group theory in a nutshell for physicist** by **A. ZEE** there you can find motivation of lie algebra from pure physics point as well as non compacts groups like poincare group etc. It will also help you to understand the $SU(5)$ etc. Grand unification.
Downside is that it is very less regrous and does not discusses young tablux etc.
You can have **Hammermesh** **group theory for physicist** for young tablux and
Certainly *Gillmore* and **JONES GROUP THEORY FOR PHYSICIST**
For extra touch.